# Bootstrap list-group: is it possible to duplicate item?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm a newbie in web development and am now starting a project using bootstrap and jquery as a start.

I might be mistaken in my understanding of web development, but I'll try asking this anyway:

I have a `list-group` of `card`s. Each card as an item (just `li`, not using `list-group-item` to preserve `card` style).

I want to be able to dynamically insert new `card`s. Currently I'm manually adding the HTML code using js/jquery. For example:

```
let card_class = document.createElement("div");
card_class.setAttribute("class", "card mx-3 my-5");
card_class.setAttribute("name", "card-class");
let row_class = document.createElement("div");
row_class.setAttribute("class", "row no-gutters bg-dark text-white-50");
row_class.setAttribute("name", "row-class");
let profile_class = '<div class="col-auto">'+
'<img src="profile.jpg" style="height:50px;" class="img-fluid" alt=""></img></div>';
let col_class = document.createElement("div");
col_class.setAttribute("class", "col");
col_class.setAttribute("name", "col-class");
let card_col_class = document.createElement("div");
card_col_class.setAttribute("class", "card-block px-2");
card_col_class.setAttribute("name", "card-col-class");
let card_footer = '<div class="card-footer"><span class="btn-toolbar btn-group-sm px-5">'+
    '<button type="button" class="btn text-white-50 mx-auto rounded-circle" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#post-comment"><i class="far fa-comment-alt"></i></button>'+
    '<button type="button" class="btn text-white-50 mx-auto rounded-circle"><i class="fas fa-retweet"></i></button>'+
    '<button type="button" class="btn text-white-50 mx-auto rounded-circle"><i class="far fa-heart"></i></button>'+
    '<button type="button" class="btn text-white-50 mx-auto rounded-circle"><i class="far fa-share-square"></i></button></span></div>';

//get the tweet info (object parameter) and put it in the header and body of the card.
let username = tweet_info.username;
let tweet = tweet_info.tweet;
let card_header = '<div class="card-header"><a href="#" class="link text-decoration-none">@'+username+'</a></div>';
let card_body = '<div class="card-body" style="white-space: pre-wrap;" onclick="setInfo(this)" type="button"'+
                'data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tweet-id">'+tweet+"</div>";

//now actually add the card to the html.
$("div[name='main-content'").prepend(card_class);
$("div[name='card-class']").append(row_class);
$("div[name='row-class']").append(profile_class);
$("div[name='row-class']").append(col_class);
$("div[name='col-class']").append(card_col_class);
$("div[name='card-col-class']").append(card_header);
$("div[name='card-col-class']").append(card_body);
$("div[name='card-col-class']"]).append(card_footer);
```

What I wondered is, how can I simplify my code.

I thought, is it possible to for example take an `li` item, duplicate it and just change it a bit?

---

Edit:

For example, the HTML code to duplicate (same as the js code):

```
<li class="card">
    <div class="row no-gutters bg-dark text-white-50">
        <div class="col-auto">
            <img src="profile.jpg" style="height:50px;" class="img-fluid" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card-block px-2">
                <div class="card-header"><a href="#" class="link text-decoration-none">@Username</a></div>
                <div class="card-body" onclick="setInfo(this)" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tweet-id">Content</div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                    <span class="btn-toolbar btn-group-sm px-5">
                        <button type="button" class="btn mx-auto text-white-50 rounded-circle"><i class="far fa-comment-alt"></i></button>
                         <button type="button" class="btn mx-auto text-white-50 rounded-circle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#comments"><i class="far fa-comments"></i></button>
                         <button type="button" class="btn mx-auto text-white-50 rounded-circle"><i class="fas fa-retweet"></i></button>
                         <button type="button" class="btn mx-auto text-white-50 rounded-circle"><i class="far fa-heart"></i></button>
                         <button type="button" class="btn mx-auto text-white-50 rounded-circle"><i class="far fa-share-square"></i></button>
                     </span>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.clone()` to clone your html element then use `.find()` to change any element inside this cloned element and finally append same to your `ul` using `appendTo` method.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$("#cloned").on("click", function() {
  var cln = $("ul li:first").clone() //cloned first li
  cln.find(".link").text("something") //use find and change username
  cln.find(".card-body").text("something something...") //use find and change content
  $(cln).appendTo($("ul")) //append to ul
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="card">
    <div class="row no-gutters bg-dark text-white-50">
      <div class="col-auto">
        <img src="profile.jpg" style="height:50px;" class="img-fluid" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card-block px-2">
          <div class="card-header"><a href="#" class="link text-decoration-none">@Username</a></div>
          <div class="card-body" onclick="setInfo(this)" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tweet-id">Content</div>
          <div class="card-footer">
            <span class="btn-toolbar btn-group-sm px-5">
                        <button type="button" class="btn mx-auto text-white-50 rounded-circle"><i class="far fa-comment-alt"></i></button>
                         <button type="button" class="btn mx-auto text-white-50 rounded-circle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#comments"><i class="far fa-comments"></i></button>
                         <button type="button" class="btn mx-auto text-white-50 rounded-circle"><i class="fas fa-retweet"></i></button>
                         <button type="button" class="btn mx-auto text-white-50 rounded-circle"><i class="far fa-heart"></i></button>
                         <button type="button" class="btn mx-auto text-white-50 rounded-circle"><i class="far fa-share-square"></i></button>
                     </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<button id="cloned">Clone Me</button>
```